# Largest possible page size for a mapping?

Tags: operating-system, paging, memory-address, virtual-memory

This is a homework question in a operating system class which I am having problems with, could anyone guide me on how to do these type of question.

What is the largest page size that could be used for this mapping, if we have a system where:

a) the virtual address 0x52D2C3A3 is mapped to physical address 0x13A103A3

b) the virtual address 0x52D2C4A4 is mapped to physical address 0x13A104A4

c) the virtual address 0x52D2C4A5 is mapped to physical address 0x13A104A5

Answer (score 0):

Without doing your homework . . . .

You have to observe that b and c have sequential virtual addresses and physical addresses. Because B is larger than A and it not an even value it cannot be the start of a page. Therefore, B and C must be in the same page.

A is 101 virtual bytes and 101 physical bytes from B. Therefor A and B may or may not be on the same page.

This makes me think that you may have copied the problem wrong because the page size could be huge. In any event, that is the approach you would use to analyze this type of [stupid] problem.